# R function for finding the ratio of two variables

Tags: r

I have an excel file dataset containing three different variables, and I need to find the ratio of two variables out of the three variables. Please, how can I get that sorted? I am new into programming!!!
[Non-Responders and Population Patient Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30J3g.jpg)

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put some time to learn how to pose questions that the community could help you.

I hope this is a good solution for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(var1 = sample(1:100,20),
             var2 = sample(1:100,20),
             var3 = sample(1:100,20))

# Now let's use mutate to create a fourth column and define it as the ratio of var1 / var 2:

df %>% mutate(ratio1_2 = var1/var2) %>% 
  
# And also let's sort the table according to the ratios

arrange(ratio1_2)
```